# Does using startForeground(int, Notification) in a Service acquire a WakeLock?

Tags: android, service, wakelock

I'm having a hard time figuring out if I need to acquire a WakeLock if I'm also using startForeground().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`startForeground()` does not automatically acquire a `WakeLock`. Whether you need a `WakeLock` depends upon what your service is doing.

Comment: Clear and concise answer. Thank you! I'm recording audio in the background which needs to proceed even if the device is asleep but I have an option to have an ongoing notification so the user knows it's happening.

Comment: @Logician: More important than just the `Notification` (which you could do without `startForeground()`), `startForeground()` gives your process foreground priority, reducing the odds of it getting shut down due to low memory, and giving you more CPU time. However, please be judicious in its use, and make sure that you're *not* using any more CPU time than is necessary, lest your service interfere with something the user is really doing with the device, causing the user to spew profanities in your general direction.